# Representability of the tensor functor with a vector space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $V$ a vector space over $k$. Does anybody know a proof of the fact that the functor of $k$-algebras
$$
R \longmapsto V \otimes_k R
$$ is **not** representable by a scheme when $V$ has infinite dimension?

Comment: This argument is also the proof of Claim 3.1 in my paper at the following URL: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602646.pdf

Comment: Here is a proof when the dimension of $V$ is countably infinite.  For $R=k[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^2\rangle$, consider the subspace $V\otimes_k \epsilon R $ of $V\otimes_k R$. If the functor is representable by a $k$-scheme $X$, for the stalk of the structure sheaf $(\mathcal{O},\mathfrak{m})$ at the $k$-point of $X$ representing the zero vector in $V$, the vector space above equals the vector space $\text{Hom}_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2,k)$.  This vector space is uncountably generated if $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has infinite dimension.

Comment: Another proof: let $F$ be the functor in question. Then the natural map $F(k[[t]])\to\varprojlim_n F\left(k[[t]]\,/\,(t^{n+1})\right)$ is not surjective. It would be bijective if $F$ were representable.

Comment: This has been discussed, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6764/when-is-tensoring-with-a-module-representable-by-a-scheme?rq=1